# creating a custom group and and field using extension

Tags: extension

I am trying to create a custom group and custom field using extension.
I created seperate funtion

```
function custom_group_create_example() {
$params = array(
    'title' => 'Test_Group_1',
    'name' => 'test_group_1',
    'extends' => array(
        '0' => 'Individual',
    ),
    'weight' => 4,
    'collapse_display' => 1,
    'style' => 'Inline',
    'help_pre' => 'This is Pre Help For Test Group 1',
    'help_post' => 'This is Post Help For Test Group 1',
    'is_active' => 1,
);

try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('CustomGroup', 'create', $params);
}
catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    // Handle error here.
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
    $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
    return array(
        'is_error' => 1,
        'error_message' => $errorMessage,
        'error_code' => $errorCode,
        'error_data' => $errorData,
    );
}

return $result;
```

}

I call this funtion into

> function contact_civicrm_install()

this funtion(hook).
But problem is that it is not creating any custom group.
How to resolve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by: "I call this funtion into function contact_civicrm_install()
this funtion(hook). "? I am unclear what you are doing here, and contact is probably not a very smart name for an extension and invites clashes. Will add an example as answer.

Comment: Finally, it's work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I add custom groups and fields:

- as a first step, add an upgrader to your extension with civix generate:upgrader
- then add the call to your creating function to the install function in the upgrader:

```
     public function install() {
        // install custom groups and fields
        CRM_Example_CustomData::createGroupsAndFields();
```

- I also think your extends does not have to be an array? I use

```
'extends' => 'Individual',
```